# Minus sign breaking equation extraction

Tags: regex, pcre

I'm trying to make a regular expression that extracts the numerical constants and operators from an equation.

For example, given the input `X_1 + 1234 * 5678 + 2` (where `X_1` isn't a constant, so it's ignored), I want to extract the `1234 * 5678 + 2`.

I have a regular expression that works for the above case, but it breaks when the first number is negative.

Here's my current regular expression (spaces added for clarity):

`\b( (?:-?\d+) (?:\s*[\*\+]\s* (?:-?\d+))+ )\b`

However, if the *first* numerical constant is negative, the minus sign is skipped.
For example, with an input of `X_2 * -128 + 18 * 3`, the expression extracts `128 + 18 * 3`, dropping the `-` from `128`.

I believe the issue is the leading word boundary anchor, but without it the `2` from `X_2` is included, which is incorrect.  What can I do to correctly include negative numbers but without accidentally including variables?

---

**Edit:** For the sake of simplicity, a "variable" is anything that's not a numerical constant.  A "numerical constant" is a positive or negative integer value.  In my above expression, they're matched with `(?: -?\d+)`.

Comment: Here's an example of my current expression: http://regex101.com/r/bP4zG0/2

Comment: Can you post some more inputs. Especially where `X_1` goes by a different name. We need to see the different patterns of your variable

Comment: Have you tried a regex debugger? https://www.debuggex.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes word boundary is indeed creating problem since it is matched before or after a word and hyphen is not considered a word character hence `\b-` will never be matched.

You can use alternation to match either `-` or `\b` in your regex:

```
( (?:(?:-|\b)\d+) (?:\s*[*+]\s* (?:-?\d+))+ )\b
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/qL2sN1/1)

Comment: Gah!  I tried something like this earlier but forgot to remove the leading `\b`.  Looks like this does the trick!

Answer (score 1):

The minus is skipped because the spot between `-` and the next digit is itself a word boundary.  Using `\b` is *probably* not necessary.  I would expect each operand to be separated by spaces:

```
\s((?:-?\d+)(?:\s*[\*\+]\s*(?:-?\d+))+)\s
```

Comment: Got anything that works where operands *aren't* separated by spaces?  The examples I gave above had spaces added for readability, but the input I'm working with may not be so predictable.

Answer (score 0):

If the variable always a letter in it and is alway on the left try using this more readable regex:

```
-?\d+(?=\d+).*
```

[Test it here](http://regex101.com/r/bP4zG0/3)